# How to merge JSON objects based on key/value pair?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongodb

I need to combine results from two different documents in Mongo. I have a function like this:

```
async function getReviewsByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const reviews = await Review.find({ userId }).lean() || []

  return res.status(200).send(reviews.reverse())
}
```

The `reviews` array looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1263b55ef2cdd3ebb0654d1dd"),
    "launchId" : "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03111",
    "userId" : "1",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6355565cf5ef2cddebb065584"),
    "launchId" : "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
    "userId" : "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03112",
}
```

I need to use the `launchId` from each review, look up a `launch` object from my mongo database, and combine that with the correct object in the `reviews` array.

Example of what I mean:

```
async function getReviewsByUserId (req, res) {
  const { userId } = req.params

  const reviews = await Review.find({ userId }).lean() || []

  const launches = await Launch.find(/* find all launches where launch._id is equal to reviews.launchId*/)

  return res.status(200).send(launches.reverse())
}
```

So if `launches` data looks like this (and launches is also an array of ALL launches):

```
{
    "_id" : "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
    "name" : "The Park",
}
```

Then how can I merge this with the `reviews` payload where the `launch._id == reviews.launchId` so that the final data looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("1263b55ef2cdd3ebb0654d1dd"),
    "launchId" : "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03111",
    "userId" : "1",
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6355565cf5ef2cddebb065584"),
    "launchId" : "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
    "userId" : "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03112",
    "launch": {
        "_id" : "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
        "name" : "The Park",
    }
}
```

Comment: is `launch._id` unique?

Comment: yes it is unique

Comment: im trying to figure out how to use populate as it seems that is the solution but not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved by using [aggregate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html#aggregate_Aggregate) pipelines.

1. Filter `reviews` by `userId` in `$match` stage
2. `$lookup` for `launches`
3. `$unwind` the `launch` array to an object

The solution could be:

```js
  async function getReviewsByUserId(req, res) {
    const { userId } = req.params;

    const launches = await Review.aggregate([
      {
        $match: {
          userId
        }
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "launches",
          localField: "launchId",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "launch"
        }
      },
      {
        $unwind: {
          path: "$launch",
          preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
        }
      }
    ]);

    return res.status(200).send(launches.reverse());
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `map()` your reviews, and for each item you can use `find()` on the `launches` array to check if the launch id matches the current review id.

If there is no match, just return the review unaltered; if you get a match, you add the `launches` property to the current review and return it.

```js
function ObjectId(oid) {
  return oid
}

const reviews = [{
    "_id": ObjectId("1263b55ef2cdd3ebb0654d1dd"),
    "launchId": "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03111",
    "userId": "1",
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("6355565cf5ef2cddebb065584"),
    "launchId": "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
    "userId": "7fb83b40-7c6f-4099-aaed-fe9d0dc03112",
  }
]

const launches = [{
  "_id": "12b53940-136f-3399-aaed-fe9d0dc05473",
  "name": "The Park",
}]


const res = reviews.map(r => {
  const found = launches.find(l => l._id === r.launchId)

  if (found) {
    r.launch = {
      _id: found._id,
      name: found.name
    }
    return r
  } else {
    return r
  }
})

console.log(res)
```